# Extracting only one element from the list that i have created

Tags: python, list

**Agenda:**

Simply, I want to change binary number to decimal.I know Python has builtin function for achieving this goal ,but I want it manually with the code

**Problem :**

I am getting stuck in extracting the element from list created with the length user input .It gives me only one value from the list that I have created with the length is user input

**My code:**

```
user_input = int(input("Enter the binary number "))
change_user_input_to_list = [int(x) for x in str(user_input) ]
# print(type(change_user_input_to_list))
# print(len(change_user_input_to_list))
length_of_user_input = len(change_user_input_to_list)
list_created_with_length_of_user_input = []

for i in range(length_of_user_input):
    calculation_for_making_list_with_length_of_user_input = 2**i
    list_created_with_length_of_user_input.append(calculation_for_making_list_with_length_of_user_input)

print(list_created_with_length_of_user_input)
result =0
coun = 0

#problem is here

while coun <length_of_user_input:
    if list_created_with_length_of_user_input[coun]==1:
        print(list_created_with_length_of_user_input[coun])
    coun= coun+1

print(result)
```

Comment: Descriptive variables are nice, but those_variable_names_are_way_too_long!

Comment: ☝️ I agree. FWIW, "`change_user_input_to_list`" isn't even correct. The *change* is happening on the right hand side of `=`, the *result* should be called `user_input_list`, if anything.

Comment: you can use `sum([2**i*int(x) for i,x in enumerate(reversed(input("Enter the binary number ")))])` to get convert binary to decimal

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if list_created_with_length_of_user_input[coun]==1:` we need to check `if change_user_input_to_list[coun]==1:`.

Code with minimum changes:

```
user_input = int(input("Enter the binary number "))
change_user_input_to_list = [int(x) for x in str(user_input) ]
length_of_user_input = len(change_user_input_to_list)
list_created_with_length_of_user_input = []

for i in range(length_of_user_input):
    calculation_for_making_list_with_length_of_user_input = 2**i
    list_created_with_length_of_user_input.append(calculation_for_making_list_with_length_of_user_input)

result =0
coun = 0

while coun <length_of_user_input:
    if change_user_input_to_list[coun]==1:
        result += list_created_with_length_of_user_input[coun]
    coun= coun+1

print(result)
```

Note:

If the input is `10111`, then your code will convert the reversed binary number `11101` to the decimal which is `29`.

Answer (score 0):

```
b_num = list(input("Enter the binary number "))
value = 0

for i in range(len(b_num)):
    digit = b_num.pop()
    if digit == '1':
        value = value + pow(2, i)
print("The decimal value of the number is", value)
```

This is simplest way to convert binary to decimal hope it will work as your expectation